# Highlighting strings in Org and Markdown mode doesn't work with *bold* or /italic/

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions, faces, font-lock, markdown-mode

I want to highlight strings between double quotation marks in org-mode and markdown-mode, just so they're easier to see, as in LaTeX-mode.  I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
;; Highlight strings delimited by double quotations in Org Mode
;; buffers, please
(defface org-string-face
  (let ((font '(:inherit italic)))
    `((((type tty) (class color))
       (:foreground "green"))
      (((class grayscale) (background light))
       (:foreground "DimGray" ,@font))
      (((class grayscale) (background dark))
       (:foreground "LightGray" ,@font))
      (((class color) (background light))
       (:foreground "RosyBrown"))
      (((class color) (background dark))
       (:foreground "LightSalmon"))
      (t (,@font))))
  "Face used to highlight strings."
  :group 'org-faces)

(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode   ;;
            '(("\"[^\"]*\"" . 'org-string-face)) t)
(font-lock-add-keywords 'markdown-mode  ;;
            '(("\"[^\"]*\"" . 'org-string-face)) t)
```

This works, in other words any characters between `"` and `"` as well as the quotation marks will show the desired fortification *unless* I accent any words within the quotation marks.  So the org-mode and markdown-mode emphasis markings `*` and `/` do show their emphasis, but then the entire string is unfontified.  I'm not sure why this doesn't work because the regex above should capture everything (not just `[:alnum:]`) between quotation marks.  Yes, it works across lines.

Just in case anyone has a different solution, I am writing fiction with multiple languages in dialogue, with English as the primary language and other languages interspersed occasionally, marked with italics.

Edit: let me just add that the above regex works interactively, i.e. interactive regex functions such as Regexp I-search and `regexp-builder`.